# Should I delete a release if it has big errors?

Tags: github, version-control

I use Github for managing my code.
Is it bad style if I would delete a release which has a big and clear error and people will have trouble with it?

The thing here is that on my machine I had no troubles, but if you are on MAC the plugin will bomb the application.
What do you do in these cases?

Comment: I would patch the release with a sub version number. So if your current version 1.2 then the patched version would be 1.2.1. I am not so trilled about deleting releases. This can get very confusing

Comment: @AgeDeO well yes, this is what I'm currently doing, and I also think it's more convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just release a new version increasing the patch level, this is called semantic versioning.

If your version number is 1.0.0, release a new one with number 1.0.1, and explain which bugs were fixed in your changelog file.